# Another How to get Page Loading to work in JavaScript or jQuery, this time with variable display text

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying (for days!) to get javascript to load a “please wait” type screen with the ability to change the displayed text by parameter. This is so that, in a larger project, I can display the spinning wheel with some indication to the user as to what is going on. It needs to work on all modern Browsers.

The best approach for the text changing seems to be the dynamic addition and removal of a div at the start of the HTML. This is achieved by prependHtml and the startModal function adding the PopupMask div. stopModal simply removes the PopupMask div.

The problem I have is that the background and spinning gif don’t display, unless I put a breakpoint in in any time after startModal is initiated. Then it displays when the breakpoint is hit.

I have tried using straight function calls (as provided below), the use of ajaxStart and ajaxStop (see “startModalajax” function example), and using eventListeners – none seem to work. At one point I had it working on FireFox but it wouldn’t work on Chrome. (Unfortunately I overwrote that code).
The test code I provide below simply calls the function “test” when I click on the “Click Anywhere here to test the start and stop Modals”, which waits for 5 seconds, displaying on the Console each second then stopModal is called to remove the PopupMask.

I know there are many solutions provided in StackOverflow, but none of them seem to actually work on all browsers, or don’t allow the text to be changed by parameter passing. Or (more likely!) I’m doing something wrong

TIA

```js
    HTMLElement.prototype.prependHtml = function (element) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = element;
        this.insertBefore(div, this.firstChild);
    };
    
  function startModalajax(text) {
      $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        if (text===undefined) {text = "teest";}
            
        if (!document.getElementById("PopupMask")) {
            document.body.prependHtml("<div id='PopupMask' style='position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:10;background-color:#00B3EF;'><span class='spinnertext'>" + text + "<br><br><br><br><br><br></span><img src= 'https://www.samfordsupportnetwork.com/wp-content/themes/u-design-child/SSN-Spinner.gif' class='spinner' </img></div>");}
    
        document.getElementById("PopupMask").style.opacity = 0.9;
    });
    }// end function startModal

  function startModal(text) {
//console.log($(this).text);
        if (text===undefined) {text = "teest";}
            
        if (!document.getElementById("PopupMask")) {
            document.body.prependHtml("<div id='PopupMask' style='position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:10;background-color:#00B3EF;'><span class='spinnertext'>" + text + "<br><br><br><br><br><br></span><img src= 'https://www.samfordsupportnetwork.com/wp-content/themes/u-design-child/SSN-Spinner.gif' class='spinner' </img></div>");}
    
        document.getElementById("PopupMask").style.opacity = 0.9;
//    });
    }// end function startModal

    
    function stopModal() {
 //      $(document).ajaxStop(function(){ <<<< Used when testing ajaxStop
       if (!document.getElementById("PopupMask")) {
            return;
            
        } else {
        document.getElementById("PopupMask").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("PopupMask"));
        }
        
        if (!document.getElementById("PopupMask")) {
            return;
            
        } else {
        document.getElementById("PopupMask").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("PopupMask"));
        }
    
//       });   //for ajaxstop
    } // end function stoptModal
    
    
    function wait(ms){
       var start = new Date().getTime();
       var end = start;
       while(end < start + ms) {
         end = new Date().getTime();
      }
    }


    
//    startModal("Page initialising - please wait");


    function test () {   
        startModal("Test Start Modal text");
        for (i=1; i<5; i++) {
            console.log(i * 1000);
            wait(1000);
        };
        stopModal();
    }
```

```css
.spinnertext{
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    
}
.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
   <!-- Load jQuery modules  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script> src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"</script>

<body>
        <span class="SSN_H3_Blue" id="myelement" style="vertical-align:middle;" onclick="test(this);">Click Anywhere here to test the start and stop Modals</span>
    </body>
```

Comment: @sergey-kuznetsov Thank you for reformatting the code and adding Run Code snippet

Comment: Can anyone help please?